# Is there a good word for "unsurpassability"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I hope that this is a good forum to post the query below, and please excuse me if it is not -- this is my first visit.

I am looking for a noun that describes a state of not being surpassable or exceedable (similar to how "impossibility" describes the state of not being possible).  Is there such a word? "Unsurpassability" seems very awkaward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could [insuperable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insuperable)  fit what you have in mind?

> incapable of being surmounted, overcome, passed over, or solved 
>   — in·su·per·a·bly  adverb

Comment: This is a perfect word for what I am trying to describe (a mathematically-provable limit).  Thank you!  But is "insuperability" a word?  Here is a fragment my sentence: "The ______ of limit X implies..."  I am trying to be terse.

Comment: Yes it is, http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Insuperability

Comment: But why would you say 'insuperable' if you meant 'unsurpassable'?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, "unsurpassability" doesn't sound right...

Comment: 'The ______ of limit X ...' is tautologous. Why not 'the fact that the limit X exists ...' / 'X being an upper / a lower bound ...'?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the context you want to use the word in

Consider:

**unmatchable**

> eminent beyond or above comparison; "matchless beauty"; "the team's nonpareil center fielder"; "she's one girl in a million"; "the one and only Muhammad Ali"; "a peerless scholar"; "infamy unmatched in the Western world"; "wrote with unmatchable clarity"; "unrivaled mastery of her art" -*the free dictionary*

**incomparable**

> beyond comparison; matchless or unequaled: incomparable beauty.  -*dictionary.com*

The Free Dictionary also gives the following as synonynms and related words:

> matchless, nonpareil, one and only, peerless, unrivaled, unrivalled, unmatched, one, incomparable, uncomparable